# Error The non-generic type '…' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have read many of this problems but I can't uderstand and solve my problem.

I'm trying to made a communication transfer and receive message.

I find out this code on internet but I cannot compile it:

```
Public class Mex<TRXStruct, TTXStruct> : IDisposable where TRXStruct: struct where TTXStruct: struct
{
    private SerializableQueue<RXMessage<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>> RX;
    private SerializableQueue<TXMessage<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>> TX;
}

[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
protected struct RXMessage : IEquatable<Mex<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>.RXMessage> {..}

[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
protected struct TXMessage : IEquatable<Mex<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>.TXMessage> {..}
```

In another cs file i have

```
public class SerializableQueue<T>{..}
```

This error code appears and I cannot compile, I cannot understand what is the problem:

the non-generic type 'Mex.RXMessage' cannot be used with type arguments'

the non-generic type 'Mex.TXMessage' cannot be used with type arguments'

Comment: Well yes, you've got `RXMessage<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>` which suggests that `RXMessage` is a type with two type parameters... but it doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look here

```
protected struct RXMessage :
```

you define RXMessage as a "plain" type, without generic arguents

so inside your Mex class you would define a property like this

```
private SerializableQueue<RXMessage> RX;
```

and not like this

```
private SerializableQueue<RXMessage<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>> RX;
```

(note the extra arguments you applied). Applying those arguments would suggest that you coul vary and put in a different type. If that is your intention would would have to define RXMessage like this

```
public class RXMessage<TRXStruct, TTXStruct> : IEquatable<Mex<TRXStruct, TTXStruct>.RXMessage> where TRXStruct: struct where TTXStruct: struct
```